# Testing a variable against 3 tables in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i am having a hard time getting this code block to work:

```
public function verifyPayment(Request $request)
{
    $transaksie = Transaksie::where('trans_nommer', $request->trans_nommer)->firstOrFail();
    $transaksie->is_paid = 4;
    $transaksie->save();


    // Notify user that transaction was successfull
    $transaksie->user->notify(new PaymentVerified($transaksie));
      // Merk die sertifikaat as verkoop
    if($request->sert_nommer >= 1003333) {
        $sertifikaat = Alternate::where('sert_nommer', $request->sert_nommer)->firstOrFail();
        $sertifikaat->is_paid = 4;
        $sertifikaat->save();
    }elseif($request->sert_nommer <= 1003604) {
        $sertifikaat = Share::where('sert_nommer', $request->sert_nommer)->firstOrFail();
        $sertifikaat->is_paid = 4;
        $sertifikaat->save();
    }elseif($request->sert_nommer <= 50000) {
        $sertifikaat = Aandeel::where('sert_nommer', $request->sert_nommer)->firstOrFail();
        $sertifikaat->is_paid = 4;
        $sertifikaat->save();
    }
    // Notify seller that transaction was approved
    $sertifikaat->user->notify(new BetalingSuccess($sertifikaat));

    $sertifikate = Alternate::orderBy('id','DESC')->first();
    $old_sert = $sertifikate->sert_nommer;
    $aandeel_sert = $old_sert + 1;
    $transaksie->user->alternates()->create([
        'sert_nommer' => $aandeel_sert,
        'user_id' => $transaksie->user->lid_nommer,
        'aantal_aandele' => $transaksie->aandele,
        'nfc_bedrag' => $transaksie->nfc,
        'status_id' => 3,
        'is_paid' => 2,
    ]);
    $alt_sertifikate = Alternate::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();
    $tweede_sertifikaat = $alt_sertifikate->sert_nommer;
    $nfc_sert = $tweede_sertifikaat + 1;
    $transaksie->user->alternates()->create([
        'sert_nommer' => $nfc_sert,
        'user_id' => $transaksie->user->lid_nommer,
        'aantal_aandele' => $transaksie->aandele,
        'nfc_bedrag' => $transaksie->nfc,
        'status_id' => 3,
        'is_paid' => 2,
    ]);
    // Notify user van nuwe sertifikaate en stuur mail deur queue
    $user = $transaksie->user;
    dispatch(new StuurSertifikate($aandeel_sert,$nfc_sert,$transaksie,$user))->onQueue('emails');
    return redirect()->back()->with('success','Betaling was geverifieer!');
}
```

What i am trying to achieve is that the $request->sert_nommer must check if it is in the Alternates table, Share table or the Aandeel table. All this code works on my local server with no errors but when I test this on my production server I get a 404 when it reaches this part of the query

Comment: check if there is any data in live server

Comment: There is data in all three tables

Comment: There is no reason for a 404 error be thrown by these lines. What have you tried to debug that problem further?

Comment: I used telescope but there is not much information when i go through the 404 everything looks fine...let me post the entire function maybe the problem is elsewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query a little bit and it should work (not tested):

```
if($request->sert_nommer >= 1003333) {
    $sertifikaat = Alternate::where('sert_nommer', $request->sert_nommer)->first();
    if($sertifikaat){
        $sertifikaat->is_paid = 4;
        $sertifikaat->save();
    }
}elseif($request->sert_nommer <= 1003604) {
    $sertifikaat = Share::where('sert_nommer', $request->sert_nommer)->first();
    if($sertifikaat){
        $sertifikaat->is_paid = 4;
        $sertifikaat->save();
    }
}elseif($request->sert_nommer <= 50000) {
    $sertifikaat = Aandeel::where('sert_nommer', $request->sert_nommer)->first();
    if($sertifikaat){
        $sertifikaat->is_paid = 4;
        $sertifikaat->save();
    }
}
```

> The findOrFail and firstOrFail methods will retrieve the first result of the query; however, if no result is found, a  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException will be thrown. If the exception is not caught, a 404 HTTP response is automatically sent back to the user.

For more details see official [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-single-models)

Comment: Thanks for the solution and will remember to catch exceptions in the future!